# Split a address string into city, state and address in R

Tags: r, split

I have a address in a form of string given below:

```
dat = data.frame(Addresses = c("1626 Aviation Way, Albuquerque, NM 30906, USA", 
                               "1626 Aviation Way, Augusta, GA 30906, USA", 
                               "325 Main St, Stratford, CT 06615, USA", 
                               "4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd, Tampa, FL 33607, USA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to break it into 5 columns such as Street,City,State,Zip code, Postal.
How can I do this in R.

Comment: Check out `strsplit` or `regexpr`.

Comment: Or the `separate()` function in `tidyr` if you're working with a dataframe.

Comment: I tried doing this a<-strsplit(a$Adress,","). I didn't't get the proper answer. Following is the error when I am trying to write it in Data Frame:                           Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 5

Comment: what are you working with ? a data.frame ? can you use `dput()` on a subset of your object and paste the output?

Comment: @MattJewett, yeah I ma working on a data frame.

Comment: Here is the data frame:                                                                               a<-data.frame(address<-c("1626 Aviation Way,Albuquerque, NM 30906, USA", "1626 Aviation Way, Augusta, GA 30906, USA", "325 Main St, Stratford, CT 06615, USA", 
"4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd, Tampa, FL 33607, USA"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a lot of steps. You can probably do this in a lot fewer, but this is how i did it. I'm also assuming yoru data is in a dataframe to start with one address per row.

```
dat = data.frame(Addresses = c("1626 Aviation Way, Albuquerque, NM 30906, USA", 
                 "1626 Aviation Way, Augusta, GA 30906, USA", 
                 "325 Main St, Stratford, CT 06615, USA", 
                 "4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd, Tampa, FL 33607, USA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> dat
                                       Addresses
1  1626 Aviation Way, Albuquerque, NM 30906, USA
2      1626 Aviation Way, Augusta, GA 30906, USA
3          325 Main St, Stratford, CT 06615, USA
4 4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd, Tampa, FL 33607, USA
```

Now, we need to split on commas to start and then separate the state and zip later. I am also going to remove the extra spaces that come with by splitting on the commas.

```
dat2 = sapply(dat$Addresses, strsplit, ",")
dat2 = lapply(dat2, trimws)

> dat2
$`1626 Aviation Way, Albuquerque, NM 30906, USA`
[1] "1626 Aviation Way" "Albuquerque"       "NM 30906"          "USA"              

$`1626 Aviation Way, Augusta, GA 30906, USA`
[1] "1626 Aviation Way" "Augusta"           "GA 30906"          "USA"              

$`325 Main St, Stratford, CT 06615, USA`
[1] "325 Main St" "Stratford"   "CT 06615"    "USA"        

$`4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd, Tampa, FL 33607, USA`
[1] "4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd" "Tampa"                    "FL 33607"                 "USA"
```

Now, we need to get this back into a dataframe.

```
dat2 = data.frame(matrix(unlist(dat2), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> dat2
                        X1          X2       X3  X4
1        1626 Aviation Way Albuquerque NM 30906 USA
2        1626 Aviation Way     Augusta GA 30906 USA
3              325 Main St   Stratford CT 06615 USA
4 4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd       Tampa FL 33607 USA
```

Next, we can split x3 into state and zip and then drop that column.

```
dat2$State = sapply(dat2$X3, function(x) strsplit(x, " ")[[1]][1])
dat2$Zip = sapply(dat2$X3, function(x) strsplit(x, " ")[[1]][2])

dat2 = dat2[, -3]

> dat2
                        X1          X2  X4 State   Zip
1        1626 Aviation Way Albuquerque USA    NM 30906
2        1626 Aviation Way     Augusta USA    GA 30906
3              325 Main St   Stratford USA    CT 06615
4 4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd       Tampa USA    FL 33607
```

Finally, we can set the columns names and we're done.

```
colnames(dat2) = c("Street", "City", "Country", "State", "Zip")
> dat2
                    Street        City Country State   Zip
1        1626 Aviation Way Albuquerque     USA    NM 30906
2        1626 Aviation Way     Augusta     USA    GA 30906
3              325 Main St   Stratford     USA    CT 06615
4 4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd       Tampa     USA    FL 33607
```

Comment: @kristoferesen,   I am getting the following error while implementing the data frame command.   "Warning message:
In matrix(unlist(dat2), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE) :
  data length [413] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [104]"

Comment: @Kaushik does your dataframe look like mine does right before it was changed back into a dataframe?

Comment: @Kaushik make sure you include the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your original dataframe. Otherwise the addresses will be factors and strsplit won't work.

Comment: Yes, I have included StringsAsFactors=FALSE. And my data frame looks like yours. But still I ma getting the same error.

Comment: @Kaushik alright, then just start breaking up that line of code and seeing where it is going wrong. Check if unlist returns a long vector, see if the it is going into a matrix, etc

Comment: @Kaushik if you want to reply with your code i can take a look at it

Comment: below is my code: dat = data.frame(Addresses = c("1626 Aviation Way, Albuquerque, NM 30906, USA", 
                               "1626 Aviation Way, Augusta, GA 30906, USA", 
                               "325 Main St, Stratford, CT 06615, USA", 
                               "4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd, Tampa, FL 33607, USA",
                               "Austin-Bergstrom International Airport (AUS),3600 Presidential Blvd,Austin,TX 78719, USA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: dat2 = sapply(dat$Addresses, strsplit, ",")
dat2 = lapply(dat2, trimws)
dat2 = data.frame(matrix(unlist(dat2), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Could you please check?

Comment: @Kaushik its happening because the last address in there is not the same length as the other ones.

Comment: Yes, so what shall I do. Because I have a list of 100 addresses. They are of different length.

Comment: as long as its in that form or the previous forms i can make a quick fix. 1s

Comment: @ Kristofersen, Please make a quick fix then I can try.

Comment: @Kaushik if you run this `dat$Addresses = gsub("^[\\D]+", "",dat$Addresses, perl = TRUE)` after you load in your addresses it will remove everything before the first street address (as long as it doesnt start with a number)

Comment: @Kaushik Awesome. Glad to help.

Comment: You could run the gsub and then run @Alex's solution if you want. Either way you should get the same result. His is just done in a lot less code.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with one line of code. Might look a bit naive for regex experts but for the sample data it works.

```
library(stringr)

dat = data.frame(Addresses = c("1626 Aviation Way, Albuquerque, NM 30906, USA", 
                               "1626 Aviation Way, Augusta, GA 30906, USA", 
                               "325 Main St, Stratford, CT 06615, USA", 
                               "4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd, Tampa, FL 33607, USA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str_match(dat$Addresses,"(.+), (.+), (.+) (.+), (.+)")[ ,-1]
      [,1]                       [,2]          [,3] [,4]    [,5] 
[1,] "1626 Aviation Way"        "Albuquerque" "NM" "30906" "USA"
[2,] "1626 Aviation Way"        "Augusta"     "GA" "30906" "USA"
[3,] "325 Main St"              "Stratford"   "CT" "06615" "USA"
[4,] "4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd" "Tampa"       "FL" "33607" "USA"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use my package `tfwstring`

Works automatically on any address type, even with prefixes and suffixes.

```
if (!require(remotes)) install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("nbarsch/tfwstring")
```

### To parse addresses:

`tfwstring::parseaddress(address, check_python=TRUE, force_stateabb=FALSE, return="char")`

**On Mac and Linux** python AND the python module `usaddress` should automatically install if missing (because unix is superior clearly).

**On Windows** it is recommended to

1. Install python yourself from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
2. Install c++ and python tools for visual studio: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
3. Use powershell to `pip3 install usaddress`
4. When running `parseaddress()` use `check_python=FALSE` to avoid issues running in the windows OS.

```
> dat = data.frame(Addresses = c("1626 Aviation Way, Albuquerque, NM 30906, USA", 
+                                "1626 Aviation Way, Augusta, GA 30906, USA", 
+                                "325 Main St, Stratford, CT 06615, USA", 
+                                "4205 Bessie Coleman Blvd, Tampa, FL 33607, USA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


> parseaddress(dat$Addresses[1])
     AddressNumber         StreetName StreetNamePostType          PlaceName          StateName            ZipCode        CountryName 
            "1626"         "Aviation"              "Way"      "Albuquerque"               "NM"            "30906"              "USA" 
> parseaddress(dat$Addresses[2])
     AddressNumber         StreetName StreetNamePostType          PlaceName          StateName            ZipCode        CountryName 
            "1626"         "Aviation"              "Way"          "Augusta"               "GA"            "30906"              "USA" 
> parseaddress(dat$Addresses[3])
     AddressNumber         StreetName StreetNamePostType          PlaceName          StateName            ZipCode        CountryName 
             "325"             "Main"               "St"        "Stratford"               "CT"            "06615"              "USA" 
> parseaddress(dat$Addresses[4])
     AddressNumber         StreetName StreetNamePostType          PlaceName          StateName            ZipCode        CountryName 
            "4205"   "Bessie Coleman"             "Blvd"            "Tampa"               "FL"            "33607"              "USA"
```